# How to set headers to $.get() or $.post() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How do I add authorization headers to the following `ajax` request?

```
$.get(urlAPI + "/api/account/get", function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }, 'json');
```

Comment: Just use the headers field,  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can define ajaxsetup before your request $ .get () to include the authorization in the header

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers:{
      'Authorization': "auth username and password"
   }
});

$.get(urlAPI + "/api/account/get", function (data) {
    alert(data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Didn't know that was a feature. Thanks!

Comment: this answer helped me a lot!

Comment: [Official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) strongly recommends against using this API: _"The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so."_

Answer (score 8):

based on jquery page [$.get() document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
from version 1.12 there is a settings option to pass the base settings to the method.

```
jQuery.get( [settings ] )
```

or

```
$.get( [settings] )
```

`settings` is a plain object so you can use it like

```
{ 
  url: 'http://requesturl.io', 
  data: {},
  headers: { 'your-custom-header': 'custom-header-value' }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'foo/bar',
  headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

here a simple way

```
$http.get('www.google.com/someapi', {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
});
```

Comment: Tried this but it does not work. It sends headers as request parameters instead of header.